# Class does not exist for laravel routes

Tags: php, routes, laravel-routing, laravel-5.1

**Laravel 5.1**

This seems strange to me:

```
Route::group([
    'middleware'=>['auth','acl:view activity dashboard'],
    'prefix' => 'api/v1'
], function(){
    Route::controller('investment-transactions', 'Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController');
    Route::controller('investment-transactions/{offeringID}', 'Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering');
});
```

Seems pretty normal to me, the controller:

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Investments;

use App\Brewster\Models\Company;
use App\Http\Requests;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class InvestmentTransactionsController extends Controller {

    public function __construct() {

    }

    public function getIndex() {
        echo 'Here';
    }

    public function getTransactionsForOffering($offeringID) {
        echo $offeringID;
    }
}
```

Ok so the action and the controller do exit, but when I run: `php artisan routes:list` I get:

```
 [ReflectionException]                                                                                                     
  Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering does not exist
```

Well obviously `App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering` is not a class, how ever: `App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController` is and `getTransactionsForOffering` is an action.

**Whats going on?**

Comment: Try 

`Route::controller('investment-transactions', 'InvestmentTransactionsController@Index');
Route::controller('investment-transactions/{offeringID}', 'InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering');`

Comment: What is the path of your custom controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your problem is in the routes.php we can use controllers as follows

```
Route::get('investment-transactions', 'InvestmentTransactionsController@index');
Route::get('investment-transactions/{offeringID}', 'InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering');
```

By default, our controllers are stored in **App/http/controllers** folder and laravel know it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you only need to reference the Class like so:

```
Route::controller('investment-transactions','InvestmentTransactionsController@Index'); //make sure you create a function for the index
Route::controller('investment-transactions/{offeringID}', 'InvestmentTransactionsController@getTransactionsForOffering');
```

Assuming you need to show a view for the route `investment-transactions` create the following function in your controller:

```
public function index()
{
    return view('name-of-your-view-file');
}
```

Comment: When I do that I get: `Class App\Http\Controllers\Api\V1\Investments\InvestmentTransactionsController@Index does not exist` When I try `@getIndex`, its the same error but with `@getIndex` @aqq

Comment: What's the path of your controller?